# Search data from datagridview using textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a Textbox and i want that when we enter something in Textbox,it will search that data from Datagridview . I searched lot on this but find that search is gone through database but i want that  search is gone from the datagridview.

Comment: What keeps you from accessing [DataGridView.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your purposes?

Comment: DataGridViews are primarily used for displaying data. Do the filtering on the underlying data source.

Comment: actually my datagridview datasource is csv file and it reads data from csv file

Comment: do you want to search the whole grid or specific columns?

Comment: @user3500705 What is the [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) of the object bound to the `DGV`?

Comment: i want to search the whole datagridview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will search for the text in the text box is present or not in datagridview @ any cell in the grid( search the whole grid)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim temp As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To gv.ColumnCount - 1
            If gv.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString = TextBox1.Text Then
                MsgBox("Item found")
                temp = 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If temp = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Item not found")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The following examples, using [language-integrated query (LINQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx), will test the formatted value of each cell in the grid to the given condition and return an array of matched cells.

**Exact match** (a = b)

```
Dim match As DataGridViewCell() = (From row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows From cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells Select cell Where CStr(cell.FormattedValue) = Me.TextBox1.Text).ToArray()
```

**Pattern match** (a LIKE %b%)

```
Dim match As DataGridViewCell() = (From row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows From cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells Select cell Where CStr(cell.FormattedValue).Contains(Me.TextBox1.Text)).ToArray()
```